# How to add a header or logo to highcharts exported PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm trying to customize a highcharts exported pdf.
I'm trying to add a header containing our organization logo.

I'm using a piece of code like that:

```
chart.setTitle(
        {
         useHTML: true,
         text: "<table> <tr><td><h3>test header</h3></td><td><img src='../images/logo.png' alt='img'/></td></tr>  </table>    "
        }
        );
```

both the text (test header) and the image are showen in the .aspx page, but the exported pdf file shows the text only and doesn't show the image.

How to solve this?

Comment: is the logo a static file or the logo can be change?

Comment: Let's assume that it is static, for now.

Comment: Are you using the built in exporter? Your URL is relative. an absolute URL might help.

Comment: The comment above is right. In short: if you are using default Highcharts exporting server, then your image is send to Highcharts with relative path, so Highcharts can not pick this up later. Use absolute URL instead.

Comment: I converted the logo into base64 as @Zamboney suggests. But it still show it in .aspx page only.

Answer (score 0):

if its a static logo then you could try change the logo url to [base64](http://www.dailycoding.com/utils/converter/imagetobase64.aspx). then, as the pdf being generated, the relatives of the image is not longer a factor

Comment: How can I use this very long 64-code. Where to add this code??

Comment: replace it in the `src` attribute on the `<img>` tag

Comment: Now it is not displayed any where. It disappeared from .aspx, too.

Comment: sry the link i send isn't good try this one [link](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php)

Comment: Now it is displayed in .aspx. But it still is not displayed in exported pdf.